# In the derivation of the formula for volume of a solid of revolution, how does $Δx$ "become" $\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am currently learning about the formula for the volume of a solid of revolution formed by the rotation about the $x$-axis through 2$\pi$ radians. I believe this is called the "disk" method.

Referring to the section of [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Area_Volume_Formulas.aspx) website "Volumes for Solid of Revolution", I am able to fully understand how one would eventually arrive at the formula:
$$
V \approx \sum_{i = 1}^n A(x_i^*)\Delta x.
$$
I also understand the next portion, which states that the exact volume is then:
$$
V = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i= 1}^n A(x_i^*)\Delta x.
$$
Where I have doubt is what it is next equated with, i.e. this statement of equation:
$$
V = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i= 1}^n A(x_i^*)\Delta x = \int_a^b{\rm d}x\, A(x).
$$

I understand fully how we can use integration here. What I don not understand is that how "$\Delta x$" is now replaced by $\mathrm dx$. Don't we include $\mathrm dx$ to show that we are "integrating with respect to $x$", not to represent any sort of length? And yet, $\Delta x$ was in fact supposed to represent an extremely small length. How am I supposed to understand "the transformation" of $\Delta x$ to $dx$?

Comment: I do believe it is Riemann sums.

Comment: The whole integral is just a notation used to limit (if it exist)

Comment: When you say $\delta x$ do you mean $\Delta x$?

Comment: What is the definition of $\int_a^b A(x) \, \mathrm dx$ ?

Comment: First of all, $\Delta x$ means nothing in your sums it should've had at least a subscript of $_i$ because $\Delta x_i$ means the length of the i-th interval (if you have partitioned [a,b] into i intervals)

Now that you're taking limit of these sums what you're doing you basically computing closer and closer the area under the function f on [a,b]

Now this is basically a definition of the Riemann integral (that's why it has been written $V = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i= 1}^n A(x_i^*)\Delta x_i = \int_a^b{\rm d}x\, A(x).$ EXCEPT that in the definition of the Riemann integral there is no need

Comment: there is no need for dx! Thus you could simply write $V = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i= 1}^n A(x_i^*)\Delta x_i = \int_a^b A(x).$ (note that there is no dx there and $\Delta x$ as written as $\Delta x_i$ because in the sum you simply and all of the i-lengths of the partition. Now there is also a second way to compute the area under a function f which is more general than a Riemann's integral and it's calles the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

What you're doing there is instead of taking lengths of the intervals of the partition you're taking $\alpha$-lengths of the intervals in your partition!

Comment: Now take ANY function $\alpha: R -> R$ and some arbitrary closed interval [a,b]. The $alpha-$length of [a,b] is called the number $\alpha(b) - \alpha(a)$. Only with this we now need to write $\int_a^b A(x) d\alpha$ to indicate how exactly we are computing \alpha-lengths in our Riemann-Stieltjes integral. 

Now, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral supersedes the Riemann integral. To see why take $\alpha : R-> R, \alpha(x) = x$ $ \forall x \in R$ then any \alpha-length becomes \alpha(b)-\alpha(a) = b-a and this is exactly how we are computing lengths in the Riemann integral!

Comment: Thus our Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b A(x) d\alpha$ becomes simply $\int_a^b A(x) dx$ for this concrete choice of $\alpha$ to be the identity function and since it is equal to the Riemann integral as I described earlier we simply write 

$$\int_a^b A(x) dx =  \int_a^b A(x)$$

Comment: Still, to understand full-well what is going on you should read about the construction of integrals in some book where they are defined rigorously to avoid any sort of confusion that they might raise like in your question. I would recommend Terence Tao's analysis, volume 1.

Nice, this question was asked a year ago

Comment: @famesyasd Would you say Terence Tao's book is okay for a high school student? I wanna read it and I know he's good, but I'm not sure if I can grasp what he's saying. I'd prefer explanations to be as simple as possible.

Comment: @Charlz97 okay well yes, except that here's my guide how to read it:
there are only little nuances in the first volume, second you can do all over right from the start after the first one. And the first volume you can read from the chapter 6 where the limits start.

In the first 5 chapter he constructs number that you use every day in algebra, starting from naturals, then integers rationals and reals. And in the third chapter he gives some set theory. 

Now here I would not recommend reading it if you do not have and prior knowledge about logic and set theory.

Comment: @Charlz97 still you should get accustomed with induction and cardinality of sets and how they're generated thus you can either still try to read these chapters and if you find yourself confused you can ask for some explanations in the logic room at chat.stackexchange.com (just tell them that you're high school student so that they will explain in a simple way lol) or in some other places (except that here I can not recommend much because I don't know any lol still you can ask for some recommendations in the logic room I think they can find something suitable or explain stuff themselves

Comment: @Charlz97 now Tao's explanations of stuff are very clear and concise and he gives material in a structural way so if you work through his book in a usual way (do most exercises and try to prove theorems yourself and after that comparing your proofs with the Tao's to correct for your style)
you will get somewhat complete blocks of concepts in your head. You will be able to apply theorems! (like fundamental, lagrange's intermediate, etc), the intuition you will be able to translate into math very quicly etc. Note that this only applies to analysis however.

Comment: @Charlz97 
So yeah just work through the chapter - the main thing to be able to understand stuff is to work actively on it - proving some properties, changing conditions - all that. And the only thing that can intervene into this is that stuff itself is not given rigorously so you can not prove something about it. The task is simply undefined (not well-defined) For example - in some book I've seen they give you a picture of parabola and say - the set of points that is unbounded and symmetrical above the y-axis and looks like this: is called the parabola. And then they ask you to prove that

Comment: @Charlz97 some set of points is indeed a parabola. And how can you do that with this ill-defined definition of parabola?! You can't because they have not defined rigorously what it means for a set of points to look like something. In Tao's books there is no place for this sort of confusion so the only thing required for you to work through the chapters properly and this is just a matter of mathematical maturity which you need anyway. So I would say if something is confusing in his book just work through the earlier chapter building up the maturity or you can just work right from the start

Comment: @Charlz97 it will take some time but it should have taken this time anyway you still need to build that maturity starting from somewhere eventually there is no way to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

No, the journey from $\Delta x$ to $dx$ in the notation is there to remind you of how approximating sums, in the end, turn into a definite integral. One could say that "$dx$" in the notation represents a "vanishingly small" length in the definite integral – even if that is lacking in logical rigor. But we don't need logical rigor in notation, as notation is just symbolism.

But let's start with what you've already know: the derivative. Recall that here one of our notational conventions is

$$\tag 1 \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{d y}{d x}.$$

The quantity $\Delta x$ starts off as an ordinary real variable, to be thought of as going to $0.$ Meanwhile $\Delta y,$ which is a function of $\Delta x,$ is dragged along to $0$ as $\Delta x\to 0.$ If the limit exists, the right side of $(1)$ is notation for this limit. Think of $\Delta x, \Delta y$ as turning into the "infinitely small" $dx, dy.$ It's good notation, because it reminds the reader of where everything comes from (although the notation is often abused).

On to the integral: Recall the notational convention

$$\tag 2 \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k)\Delta x = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$

Here $n\to \infty,$ and correspondingly, $\Delta x \to 0.$ If the limit exists, the right side in $(2)$ is notation for this limit. The $\sum$ sign has turned into the tall snake of an $S$ to remind you of "Sum", and $\Delta x$ has turned into $dx.$ It's no ordinary sum: We're indulging in the fantasy of adding up the areas of infinitely many rectangles, of height $f(x)$ and "infinitely small" base length $dx.$ In light of $(1),$ this makes perfect intuitive sense.

The journey from $\Delta x \to dx$ thus has much more to do with the geometric/intuitive ideas underlying the derivative and integral than to a notion of "with respect to".

I have a question for you: Why is this question occurring to you now, in studying solids of revolution, instead of earlier, when the definite integral was defined?

Comment: I like your explanation best, but I'm still trying to understand how (1) intuitively helps me understand (2). It's as if I'm trying to "compare" the terms in each to help me understand, but I know that shouldn't be the case. 

As for why this question did not occur, it's because learning solids of revolution was the first time this thing was introduced to me. In my learning, the definite integral was not defined as a sum of infinitely small rectangles. I was only taught that "the definite integral of f(x) with respect to x from a x=a to x=b, denoted by [(2) RHS] is defined to be F(b) - F(a).

Comment: You were taught that the definition of $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ is $F(b)-F(a),$ where $F'=f?$ That's unfortunate. The definition of $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ is essentially $(2).$ You can search "definition of definite integral" on Google to see this. (I'm wondering how your textbook defines it?) The result $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx =F(b)-F(a)$ is then a theorem, part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Continued below ...

Comment: In both $(1),(2)$ we have $\Delta x \to dx$ in the sense of becoming "vanishingly small". That's why I brought up the derivative, where you have seen this. That you hadn't seen this idea when the definite integral was defined seems to be at the root of your question.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$The identity (Note that $Δx = \dfrac{b - a}{n}$)$$
\lim_{n → ∞} \sum_{k = 1}^n A(x_{n, k}) · \frac{b - a}{n} = \int_a^b A(x) \,\d x
$$
is the corollary of the definition of Riemann integral. For any $n \geqslant 1$, the notation $Δx$ means a small length, whereas the notation $\d x$ means an infinitesimal length.

In fact, the “derivation” given on that site is just intuition. To prove it rigorously, denote by $D$ the solid and define the section set$$
S(x) = \{(y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid (x, y, z) \in D\}. \quad \forall a \leqslant x \leqslant b
$$
Note that for any $a \leqslant x \leqslant b$,$$
(x, y, z) \in D \Longleftrightarrow (y, z) \in S(x). \quad \forall (y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
By the definition of area and volume,\begin{align*}
V &= \iiint\limits_D \d x\d y\d z = \iiint\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} I_D(x, y, z) \,\d x\d y\d z\\
&= \int_a^b \d x \iint\limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} I_D(x, y, z) \,\d y\d z = \int_a^b \d x \iint\limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} I_{S(x)}(y, z) \,\d y\d z\\
&= \int_a^b \d x \iint\limits_{S(x)} \d y\d z = \int_a^b A(x) \,\d x.
\end{align*}
Here $I_B$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Answer (score 1):

When $a<b$ the typographical picture $\int_a^b f(x)\>dx$
has two different meanings:

$${\bf 1}:\qquad \quad\int_a^b f(x)\>dx:=F(b)-F(a)\ ,$$
where $x\mapsto F(x)$ is a primitive of $x\mapsto f(x)$, i.e., $F'(x)=f(x)$ $\>(a\leq x\leq b)$. This is meant when you are talking about "integrating with respect to $x$".
$${\bf 2}:\qquad\int_a^b f(x)\>dx:=\lim_{\ldots}\sum_{k=1}^N f(\xi_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})\ .$$
The "limit of Riemann sums" indicated here is defined in an intricate way which I don't need to explain here.

That (under reasonable assumptions) the two descriptions ${\bf 1}$ and ${\bf 2}$  give the same value is the content of the **Fundamental Theorem of Calculus** (FTC).

Now in the case of your rotational body you begin with a Riemann sum of type ${\bf 2}$, whereby $x_k-x_{k-1}$ is abbreviated to $\Delta x_k$, resp., $\Delta x$, and $f(\xi_k)$ is the area of a "median slice" cut between $x_{k-1}$ and $x_k$. You have to be aware that the **miracle** does not consist in the typographical metamorphosis $\Delta x\rightsquigarrow dx$, but in the fact that we obtain a well defined "limit over all refinements", and that this limit can be computed using the FTC.